# How subscribe to "content download" to "TTFB" in ajax calls

Tags: javascript, ajax

is there a way to find when the response from server is complete and content download has triggered in js.

For example if i have made ajax call to get a some processed data from server 
the api process it in 5 seconds (and produces the data of 10Mb)
Now if i look in chrome developer tools :-
there is TTFB which is 5 seconds
and Content Download is 15 seconds.

Is there a way in js to identify when "Content Download" as started ?

Comment: Write a line in the console with console.log?

Comment: yep . console.log would be nice